# Wording of a Problem; Croom Topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm been stuck recently on problem 10 from section 4.3 in the Croom topology book. I can't tell from the instructions whether or not the topology T being mentioned is meant to be a specific topology or "any" topology in general. It's only a rough guess, but it seems to make more sense if T is supposed to be a specific topology.

Comment: Without context, there's not much we can say.  Can you link to the reference or at least quote problem $10$ verbatim?

Comment: They mean that given an operator satisfying those conditions (a closure operator), then the set of complements of its fixed points is a topology. The second part is to show that in that topology the closure (smallest closed containing a set) is the same as applying the given closure operator. So, yes, the topology for the second part is specific. It is the one defined from the closure operator.

Comment: Is this the problem? **(from top of p. 115)** *Let* $X$ *be a set and* $\mathcal S$ *any family of subsets of* $X$ *whose union equals* $X.$ *Show that* $\mathcal S$ *is a subbasis for a topology for* $X.$ I was going to include this in your question, but after seeing @user85667's comment, I'm not sure we have the same book (or maybe not the same edition). Or perhaps you mean #10 from Section 4.2 at the top of p. 109? My copy is: Fredrick [Fred] Hailey Croom, **Principles of Topology**, The Saunders Series, Saunders College Publishing, 1989, xii + 312 pages.

Comment: That's it, top of p.115.